# Как сделать мобильный шаблон?

Tags: html, css

Интересует вопрос, как сделать шаблон для мобильных аппаратов, чтобы и ширина при входе на сайт устанавливалась автоматически и приближать нечего не надо было, на на баше.

Сделал типа такого:

```
@media only screen and (device-width: 480px) {
    body {
      width: 470px;
    }
}

@media only screen and (device-width: 320px) {
    body {
      width: 310px;
    }
}

@media only screen and (device-width: 360px) {
    body {
      width: 350px;
    }
}

@media only screen and (device-width: 240px) {
    body {
      width: 230px;
    }
}
```

Но результаты не было... Захожу через Оперу Мобайл - сайт выглядит на на компьютере, то есть все равно нужно увеличивать.

Comment: Может быть, <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">

Answer (score 1):

Не используйте четких ограничений, используйте максимальный размер и лучше без **device**, я проверял, работает

```
@media only screen and (max-width: 480px) {
    body {
      width: 470px;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Попробуйте просто:

```
 body {
    width: 100%;
 }
```